# How to remove only the objects obtained from running the last script in the R studio environment?

Tags: r, object, rstudio, environment

I have a root code in which there are many scripts. After having run for example the first 4 scripts, I could need to cancel the objects in the environment obtained from the 4th script. Is it possible ? The alternative would be rm(), but in this way I have to re-run all the scripts and this takes a while since I have a load a lot of data.

Comment: If the objects from the 4th script share something in common, like a name prefix, you could try `ls(pattern = "prefix")`. If not, you could still use `ls` after each script and have `rm` remove only the new objects.

Comment: Why don't you run the scripts for which you do not want to retain the objects in a function. That way they will be save in a different environment and destroyed when the function is done. Return only the objects you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function `rm_new()` (within your 'root code'):

```
rm_new=function( old ) {
    current=ls(,envir=parent.frame())
    to_delete = current[!(current %in% old)]
    rm( list=to_delete,envir=parent.frame() )
}
```

When you get to the end of your 'root code', remember the objects you want to keep:

```
obj_to_keep=c("obj_to_keep",ls())
```

You can now add anything you like, and use rm_new() to delete it when you're finished with it:

```
a=1:100
obj_to_keep=c("obj_to_keep",ls())

b=1:50
ls()
# [1] "a"           "b"           "obj_to_keep" "rm_new"   

rm_new( old=obj_to_keep )
ls()
# [1] "a"           "obj_to_keep" "rm_new"
```