# Is there an R function to specifically remove objects created within one script?

Tags: r

I am **not** good at keeping my RStudio environment tidy (I do not run `rm(list = ls())` after each session). I appreciate the feature that keeps many object in memory, even when the session was last opened weeks ago. I could create .Rdata for the important objects I want to find next time I open the project... But I don't systematically do it, so eventually, relying on the environment works best for me.

However, on occasion, I have scripts I need to run once and that's it. At the end of said script, I would like to remove any object that was created from the environment.

My question is: **Is there a function that remove only the objects created within the script that was just run?**

I am not looking for something that requires to conscientiously append a list of objects anytime an object is created.

A way around could be to list at the beginning of the script which objects are already in the environment, and remove at the end of the script whichever objects was created in between.

Example:

```
# Start script
initial_objects <- ls()

# Create a bunch of objects
temp <- LETTERS[1:3]
data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 10:1)
p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()

# Remove only the objects that were created since initial_objects was last run
# 1. See what is returned: should include "initial_objects" "temp" "data" "p1"  
ls()[!ls() %in% initial_objects]
# 2. Remove these objects
rm(list = ls()[!ls() %in% initial_objects])
```

[edit: user @Quinten pointed to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61680651/how-to-remove-only-the-objects-obtained-from-running-the-last-script-in-the-r-st) that basically does the same thing, although it has the same limitations than what I explain below.]

However, if I jump around 2 scripts at the same time, I may remove objects I want to keep.
On top of that, I use "temp" to create temporary objects fairly often, so when I ran this in my actual R session, it did not detect "temp" as a new object.

Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks in advance for your ideas on this!

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61680651/how-to-remove-only-the-objects-obtained-from-running-the-last-script-in-the-r-st

Comment: If you are using `source` to run the script, you can run it inside its own environment. `my_env <- new.env(); source("myscript.R", my_env); rm(my_env);`

Comment: Having said that, your question boils down to "I have some bad practices, and I want to add further complications rather than fix those bad practices". You will honestly save yourself a lot of trouble in the long run if you just stop hoarding stuff in your global workspace.

Comment: Ah, you are right, I am trying and will keep trying :)! But realistically, I don't always know what will be a relevant object until later on, so it is useful for me to keep the objects at least for a bit. Furthermore, I have some very large objects in some projects that taking a long time to save, so saving each of one as Rdata systematically present greater drawback (in my opinion and in my case) than being messy. 
However, I know for sure which objects I create and will no longer be useful immediately, which is why I am at least trying to weed out these ones.

Comment: And thank you @AllanCameron for your answer. This will be useful for at least some of the scenarios I am mentioning!!
However, in some cases, I need to visualize the output line by line, so I would rather find a solution that does something closer to what I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just found a solution that finds all the objects created within one script. The code below relies on `getParseData()` to screen the script, then `find()` to find which objects are in the environment.

I wrote the following function, `get.objects()`:

```
get.objects <- function(path2file = NULL, exception = NULL, source = FALSE, message = TRUE) {
  library("utils")
  library("tools")

  # Step 0-1: Possibility to leave path2file = NULL if using RStudio.
  # We are using rstudioapi to get the path to the current file
  if(is.null(path2file)) path2file <- rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path

  # Check that file exists
  if (!file.exists(path2file)) {
    stop("couldn't find file ", path2file)
  }

  # Step 0-2: If .Rmd file, need to extract the code in R chunks first
  # Use code in https://felixfan.github.io/extract-r-code/
  if(file_ext(path2file)=="Rmd") {
    require("knitr")
    tmp <- purl(path2file)
    path2file <- paste(getwd(),tmp,sep="/")
    source = TRUE # Must be changed to TRUE here
  }

  # Step 0-3: Start by running the script if you are calling an external script.
  if(source) source(path2file)

  # Step 1: screen the script
  summ_script <- getParseData(parse(path2file, keep.source = TRUE))

  # Step 2: extract the objects
  list_objects <- summ_script$text[which(summ_script$token == "SYMBOL")]
  # List unique
  list_objects <- unique(list_objects)

  # Step 3: find where the objects are.
  src <- paste(as.vector(sapply(list_objects, find)))
  src <- tapply(list_objects, factor(src), c)

  # List of the objects in the Global Environment
  # They can be in both the Global Environment and some packages.
  src_names <- names(src)

  list_objects = NULL
  for (i in grep("GlobalEnv", src_names)) {
    list_objects <- c(list_objects, src[[i]])
  }

  # Step 3bis: if any exception, remove from the list
  if(!is.null(exception)) {
    list_objects <- list_objects[!list_objects %in% exception]
  }

  # Step 4: done!
  # If message, print message:
  if(message) {
    cat(paste0("  ",length(list_objects)," objects  were created in the script \n  ", path2file,"\n"))
  }

  return(list_objects)
}
```

To run it, you need a saved script. Here is an example of a script:

```
# This must be saved as a script, e.g, "test.R".
# Create a bunch of objects
temp <- LETTERS[1:3]
data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 10:1)
p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()

# List the objects, and remove them if you wish. Here, I listed as exception p1.
get.objects()
rm(list = get.objects(exception = "p1", message = FALSE))
```

Note that the function also works for external script and R markdown.
If you run an external script, you will have to run the script before. To do so, change the argument `source` to TRUE.

I will validate this answer, but will keep an eye on this post in case the community has another solution to suggest!

[As Dr. @AllanCameron pointed it out, it is better to have good practices, which I agree with! But in my case, the good practices present a greater drawback than being messy: saving/loading .Rdata takes too much time (I tried, having less objects does not solves this) + my environment is not *that* messy, it is just that I do not want to remove all objects.]